# How can a windows executable .(EXE) be parallelized without accessing the source code? (Parallel Computing)

Tags: windows, parallel-processing

There is an .EXE file, I need to run this .EXE file using the computing power of multiple computers.

What are the main approaches to doing this?

Is it necessary to re-code the operating system?

Can we do it without the source code, by recoding the operating system for it, or in a different way?

Comment: To get answer you have to describe your goal at detail: fault tolerance; performance; veracity; etc.